# Homestead.test default file gives [No input file specified] Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, homestead

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 and I want to try create a website using Laravel, but I hit a rock, I followed the instructions. step by step on the official website. But I think something is missing,

Because I haven't touch / edit anything in Homestead.yaml, so basically it would working right?

I already use `vagrant up --provision`. already create the ssh key. I already googled it and try several ways but it doesn't fix it, I already turn on my XAMPP as well

Sorry but I never touched Ubuntu before, so I'm very blind using this OS

Here is my **Homestead.yaml** file

[Homestead.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgCji.png)

and the directories of **/home/workspace/** and **/home/workspace/Homestead/**

[~ Dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cxGy.png)

[Homestead Dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOgYl.png)

my **Hosts** file

[Hosts File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYpQ8.png)

**EDITED:**

I just create a new project in **~/Homestead/Projects/[it goes here]** because the default laravel installation is working already, so now I want to create a new project in Projects folder inside Homestead, but why it redirect the url to https?

[image]

The folders

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cxGy.png Your `~/code` folder appears to not exist, which means Homestead will not map it. Create that folder in your Host OS (Ubuntu 17) and then run `vagrant destroy && vagrant up` If you still have issues post the entire output here for us to check.

Comment: Before I were using `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`, it's a success. but I want to try using the `laravel new blog` command, so first I use `composer global require "laravel/installer"` but it gives me an error, saying **[RuntimeException]/home/workspace/.composer/vendor does not exist and could not be created.** why it happens?

Comment: Hi, finally it's working, but now I have another problem, can you help me? I already edited the question. thank you :)

Comment: `[RuntimeException]/home/workspace/.composer/vendor does not exist and could not be created. why it happens?` Not sure, sounds like a permissions problem?

Answer (score 0):

For my last question, why when I tried to open my new projects is always giving me this error **your internet connection is not private**. it's because I'm using **.app** or **.dev** in the of the site name, the problem is from google chrome, so I need changed it to **.test** then it's working perfectly.

I got the answer from this site 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/chrome-blocked-localhost-with-error-your-connection-is-not-private